# Distinguish between real system apps and preinstalled user apps

Tags: android

In my app I'm listing apps using following code:

```
        List<PackageInfo> packages = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        if (packages != null) for (PackageInfo package_info : packages) if ((package_info.applicationInfo != null) && (package_info.applicationInfo.packageName != null) && (! package_info.applicationInfo.packageName.isEmpty()) && ((package_info.applicationInfo.flags &  ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)) IS_SYSTEM_APP = true;
```

Using this code to distinguish between system and user apps do not works properly, due user apps that are preinstalled (like Gmail, Calendar, etc) are listed as system apps.

Is there a way to properly filter there apps as user apps?

Thanks

Comment: you might also wanna include a check for ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP

Comment: Yep, but some system apps are also updated, then some user apps aren't. Is there not another way? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not returning the correct result. Perhaps you might wanna use ApplicationInfo rather than PackageInfo? Or you can simply add logs in your loop to see which app is causing the issue. Something like List<ApplicationInfo> packages = ctx.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);

Comment: I've tried both then the retourned values are the same. By example, in the emulator, Gmail app has FLAG_SYSTEM_APP then do not has FLAG_SYSTEM_UPDATED_APP

Comment: You have to use an `OR` condition rather than `AND`. So it's something like either the application has FLAG_SYSTEM_APP `OR` FLAG_SYSTEM_UPDATED_APP